# Is it possible to view ActiveX controls on a page before I allow it to run?

Tags: activex

A website is trying to run ActiveX controls. Is there any way I can look at them before I decide whether or not to run allow them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to render itself, an ActiveX control/component needs to run.

So, no, it is impossible to get a "preview" of an ActiveX control without running it.

Comment: Is it possible to view the source code of the ActiveX after I've allowed it to run?

Comment: @aslum - ActiveX are compiled components (dlls). If they happen to be .NET assemblies there are decompilers that will decompile to equivalent source code (if not obfuscated). Other dlls may not be so easy to decompile. Not sure where they get stored though.

Comment: Note that you can view the page source and look at the object or embed tag to get an idea of what the mimetype or CLSID is, which may allow you to do a search to find more information about it.